# How can I find a folder with a specified value in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I find a folder with a specified value?

I've created a folder for every username in **UploadFolder**. When a user clicks the delete button, the folder with their username and all the files in their directory will be deleted.

I've removed it from database data but I can't make it find the folder with their username.

I can delete the specific file but **not** the *whole folder*.

This is for a new server.

```
rootFolder = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UploadFolder\Username\";
file = "filename.docx";

try
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(rootFolder, file)))
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(rootFolder, file));
        Response.Write("File deleted.");
    }
    else Response.Write("File not found");
}
catch (IOException ioExp)
{
    Response.Write(ioExp.Message);
}
```

Comment: You're only deleting the file, not the folder.

Comment: You want to delete the whole folder or only files in the folder? What problem you are facing in this code? In your code you are dealing with a folder `Username` which is static name. If you know the actual userName value then you should use it in the folder Path instead of static value.

Comment: `Directory.Delete(rootFolder);` will delete the username folder if it's empty. `Directory.Delete(rootFolder, true);` will delete the username folder and all of it's contents. This question is a little confusing because you appear to be only deleting one file in the code, but the text above mentions deleting all the contents of the folder and the folder itself.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be checking for the existence of a file and not a directory.

To manage directories then you need the System.IO.Directory class and you can use it as follows, in addition to your code for files (if you need it)

```
rootFolder = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UploadFolder\Username";  


if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))    
{    
    Directory.Delete(rootFolder);    
}
```